# Is there a workaround for using the > operator on more than one turtle breed?

Tags: operators, netlogo

My model has a a number of turtle breeds and I want them to avoid each other according to size. So turtle 1 with size = 1 will avoid turtle 2 with size = 2 and so on.

The code that generates the error is:

```
ask turtles with [color = green] 
[if not any? turtles in-radius vision with [size > self][avoid]
```

And the error I get is
"The > operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on a number and a turtle."

I think I understand the error but my question is is there a workaround for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with breeds. The problem is the one described by the error: you can't compare `size` directly with `self` (which is a turtle, *not* a number).

You need to do:

```
with [ size > [ size ] of myself ]
```

(And note that inside the `with` block, you need to use [`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself) instead of [`self`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#self).)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that